# print variable using javascript template

Tags: javascript, jquery, blueimp

I am using jquery file upload by [blueimp.net](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)

I want to add dynamic id to the table row as in javascript template section.
    for example let say i am uploading 3 file together and my template code below

```
  <script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
  {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
  <tr class="template-upload fade" id="{%=i%}_files">
```

I want it to give HTML/output as..

```
<tr class="template-upload fade" id="0_files">
<tr class="template-upload fade" id="1_files">
<tr class="template-upload fade" id="2_files">
```

How can I achieve this!